# Print rest of String after specific word

Tags: java, string, cpu-word

I have a String

> saya dan anda saya dan adik dan ayah,saya  dan siapa?

In my program, user input a word then program display only string after the word.
For example I input

> anda

I want the output is

> saya dan adik dan ayah,saya  dan siapa?

I have this code

```
String kalimat = "saya dan anda saya dan adik dan ayah,saya  dan siapa?";
int kataSebelum = kalimat.indexOf("anda");
if (kataSebelum > 0){
kalimat = kalimat.substring(kataSebelum);
 System.out.println("Kalimat baru = " +kalimat);
```

But I got

> anda saya dan adik dan ayah,saya  dan siapa?

Comment: Try - (line 4/Grey Box4) - wouldnt that solve the problem?
kalimat = kalimat.substring(kataSebelum+<USER_INPUT>.length());

Comment: Damn!! i should stop commenting and start putting **** in the answers

Comment: @Joddy it will returns "nda saya dan adik dan ayah,saya  dan siapa?"

Comment: You need to add STRING LENGTH not just ONE 
<USER_INPUT>.length() -- where <USER_INPUT> must be a string.

Comment: @Joddy Thanks. I know what you mean and now my program run well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`kalimat.indexOf("anda");` returns the start index of `"anda"`. Add the length of `"anda"` to that index to get the substring starting after the match.

```
kalimat = kalimat.substring(kataSebelum + "anda".length());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
        String remove = "quick";
        int length = remove.length();
        int idx = str.indexOf(remove);
        System.out.println("idx: " + idx);
        String output = str.substring(idx + length + 1); // add one more for the whitespace
        System.out.println(output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   String kalimat = "saya dan anda saya dan adik dan ayah,saya  dan siapa?";
            int kataSebelum = kalimat.indexOf("anda");
            if (kataSebelum > 0){
            kalimat = kalimat.substring(kataSebelum+inputStr.length());
             System.out.println("Kalimat baru = " +kalimat);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

`String.indexOf(String str)` will return to you the location of the first character that matches str. So what you need to do is to offset that value by the length of str.

```
String kalimat = "saya dan anda saya dan adik dan ayah, saya dan siapa?";
int kataSebelum = kalimat.indexOf("anda");
if(kataSebelum > 0) {
    kataSebelum += "anda".length();
    kalimat = kalimat.substring(kataSebelum);
    System.out.println("Kalimat baru = " + kalimat);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String kalimat = "saya dan anda saya dan adik dan ayah,saya  dan siapa?";
int kataSebelum = kalimat.indexOf("anda")+"anda".length;
if (kataSebelum >= "anda".length){
kalimat = kalimat.substring(kataSebelum);
System.out.println("Kalimat baru = " +kalimat);
```